# How does the JS engine deal with explicitly typed computations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, performance-testing

I've been interested in meta-programming of late. We can take a generic computation, in this case the mean, and create an efficient, spelled out function on the fly for it. Here I'm creating, in mean2, a function that will compute the mean explicitly (without loops). Generally, these explicit functions run more quickly. But I'm experiencing some interesting behavior. In my timings, for an array of size 50 ran in 4e7 loops, the explicit function wins handily as anticipated:

symbolic: 2479.273ms | literal: 60.572ms

But nudge the initial array size from 50 to say 55, the performance dives precipitously.

symbolic: 2445.357ms | literal: 3221.829ms

What could be the cause of this?

```
const A = new Float64Array(50).map(Math.random)

const mean1 = function (A) {
    let sum = 0

    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
        sum += A[i]

    return sum / A.length
}

const mean2 = (function (A) {
    return new Function('A', `
        return (${new Array(A.length).fill(null).map(function (_, i) {
            return `A[${i}]`
        }).join('+')}) / ${A.length}
    `)
})(A)

console.time('symbolic')
for (let i = 0; i < 4e7; i++)
    mean1(A)
console.timeEnd('symbolic')


console.time('literal')
for (let i = 0; i < 4e7; i++)
    mean2(A)
console.timeEnd('literal')
```

Comment: @Shidersz Mean2 is the result of an anonymous function that only runs at startup to create the template - console.log(mean2.toString()) to see what I mean

Comment: @meagar Yea I can see it now (self invoking function on initialization of `mean2`), thanks, going to delete my comment...

Answer (score 0):

The result is being cached in the 2nd example, it has little to do with the "meta-programming" method, (or more specifically the lack of a loop).

This is not so easy to directly prove with JavaScript; in a compiled language you would usually just look at the assembly and see that the compiler has tried to be clever in some way and optimise out your loop inside the timer. JS runtimes are obviously more opaque and complex, the output is not so easily accessible. You can instead test for it by proxy, by observing the behaviour of different but equivalent forms to see what triggers the up-front optimisations.

The following slight modifications of your "mean2" function escape caching optimisations in nodejs (v8) at time of testing:

Assign to a scoped variable before return:

```
const mean2 = (function (A) {
    return new Function('A', `
        let sum = (${new Array(A.length).fill(null).map(function (_, i) {
            return `A[${i}]`
        }).join('+')}) / ${A.length};
        return sum;
    `)
})(A)
```

Use `A.length` reference instead of literal:

```
const mean2 = (function (A) {
    return new Function('A', `
        return (${new Array(A.length).fill(null).map(function (_, i) {
            return `A[${i}]`
        }).join('+')}) / A.length
    `)
})(A)
```

You needn't worry about these subtitles though... instead change your testing methodology, ensure samples cannot be thrown away to produce the same result, otherwise you risk testing the compiler's ability to omit useless instructions instead of real performance.

In this case, re-initialise the array with random values before each sample, and to be absolutely sure - make some persistent variable dependent on the result of each sample. Also do not include these extra steps in the timer otherwise it will bias your sample time.